# Parsing with PHP Simple HTML DOM: URLs from CSV but in array just last URL from the list

Tags: php, csv, parsing

Trying to get all products from specific page with URLs from CSV but it's not working right. There are three arrays:

1. $test_base
2. $base - made from the CSV file
3. $words

It works right just with **$test_base**, other ones returns empty arrays except last one LINK. And I just don't understand because this LINKS arrays are identical.

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

// Getting links array
$base = file("base.txt");

$words = array();

foreach($base AS $word) {
    $words[] = $word;
}

$test_base= array("LINK_1","LINK_2","LINK_3");

// Arrays are exactly the same
print_r($test_base);
print_r($base);
print_r($words);

// Main loop for one link
foreach($test_base AS $word) {

     $html = file_get_html($word);

// Getting all info for one link    
foreach($html->find('div.item_info') as $article) {
        $item['title'] = $article->find('.item_name', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['manufacture'] = $article->find('.item_additional-info', 0)->plaintext;
        $item['price'] = $article->find('.price span', 0)->plaintext;

   $articles[] = $item;
}

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($articles);
        echo "</pre>";

$html->clear();
unset($html);

}
```

Comment: `// Arrays are exactly the same` - until you use var_dump instead of print_r and show us the output, I am just going to say I doubt that. So show us that, or go read up on how `file` works (because I suspect your problem might be caused by that.)

Comment: Here it is
**$test_base:** array(3) { [0]=> string(6) "LINK_1" [1]=> string(6) "LINK_2" [2]=> string(6) "LINK_3" }

**$base:** array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "LINK_1 " [1]=> string(7) "LINK_2 " [2]=> string(6) "LINK_3" } 

**$words:** array(3) { [0]=> string(7) "LINK_1 " [1]=> string(7) "LINK_2 " [2]=> string(6) "LINK_3" }

Also I have try a **fopen()** and **while* with **fgets()**

Comment: Well there you go, it shows the strings are 6 characters long in the first and third one, but 7 characters in the second one - so _not_ “identical”, as you claimed. And now go read the manual for the `file` function …

Comment: Oh seems like I've got it, there are spaces on the end of string in array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a **FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES** parameter to the **file()** function, and its removed a spaces at the end of the string. And now all works like it should. Thanks to all!